# How can I load an Ubuntu install image if my disc is too small?

Tags: cd

How can I install Xubuntu 14.04 on a friend's Windows XP machine? She has a 700 MB CD and wants to sideload it with XP.

I've heard of sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop with mini ISO but can it sideload? thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Download a version smaller than 700 Mb. Best version would be Ubuntu server (=667 Mb). That will install the version without a desktop and from a terminal session it is pretty easy to install a desktop after you have a working internet (only need a `sudo apt install xbuntu-desktop` and a reboot will then get you a desktop).

Yes, the same can be down with the mini ISO. But you will be pulling in more software after installing the system then with the server version. In the end it will be the same system. Regaring "sideload": that is called dual-boot. Dual boot can be achieved when you install a bootloader (GRUB is the more common one). The mini ISO installs grub for you at the end (it asks for it).

The one thing you do not want to do is format the windows partition so it is best to create unallocated space in Windows before starting.

Besides that ...

- Most obvious one would be to install from an USB stick. There is a tool for that called "startup disk creator" in Ubuntu. Something similar will be available for Windows XP.
- Get a dvd player and install from that.
- Rather difficult: create a partition, store the ISO into the partition and boot from it from your BIOS.